# Loop through each line of a variable and also cut something out

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables

I have a txt file with multiple lines in it. I am writing the content to a variable. Now I want to loop through each variable and in the same step I want to cut only one part out of the line and put this part in one remote command.

The file is a simple txt file called `$output`

I write it in a variable: `checkuser1=$(<$output)`

now I want to loop through each line of this variable and to cut only a specific part out of it and put this part into one separate remote command.

I tried something like this:

```
checkuser1=$(<$output)
for line in $checkuser1 ; do
echo "hallo" >> /tmp/file
done
```

it gives me just

```
hallo
hallo
hallo....
```

and so on.

how can I work line by line?

Comment: What do you want to cut out? Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for the proper way to read a file line-by-line in `bash`.

Comment: Also what did you expect `echo "hallo" >> /tmp/file` to do ?

Comment: Hi, the lines are username quota someotherstring. I want to cut out the quota and put it into another command.
With `echo "hallo" >> /tmp/file` i just wanted to test the loop - what it's doing

Comment: You need to say what you want to cut out.

Comment: just wanto to cut out a part of each line. i don't know how to do that with a variable for each line and then to write the value out

Answer (score 0):

You can do stuff with $line for example

```
NEW=$(echo $line|cut -c 2,4)
```

This would extract certain characters from $line (see `man cut` for details).
You can then pass this to a command, like this:

```
touch $NEW
```

The command should also be inside the for loop if you want to run it for every line.

Comment: so you mean i should place another variable and `$line` is in my case `$output` which means the file's content in the variable?
Just tested it. It gives me only the cut'ed part from the first line. How can i make this for each line?

Comment: The for loop in your example will fill the variable "line" with the entries from $checkuser1 split by $IFS

Comment: thanks for the hint with $IFS! that did also a part for what i'm looking for. will try to go on now..

Answer (score 0):

[Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Based on what you've said in the comments, you can achieve what you want using a `while read` loop:

```
while read -r username quota junk; do
    # some command using "$quota"
done < "$output"
```

This reads the file whose name is stored in the variable `$output` line by line, setting the variables `$username` and `$quota` to the values in the first and second field respectively. The rest of the line goes into the variable `$junk`.

The `-r` switch prevents the shell from attempting to interpret escape sequences in your file, which is almost always what you want.

Comment: ok this is doing it! thanks. But another little question here: how can i tell bash now that it should take each `$quota` variable and put it into another command? Now it gives me each quota to stdout. but i want bash to do something with each `$quota`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - if you want to run one command per line of the file then the loop above does what you want. If you want to pass all of the quota to another command, then you would be better off using something like `awk '{ print $2 }' "$output" | xargs command`. Either way, you should edit your question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do so we can help you better.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Now 
`while read -r username ; do
echo "$username"
done < "$file"`
gives me the the variable username of each line. And now i want to take every `$username` and pass it to another command to check something remotely.. I dont know the syntax to do the looping throug each line.

Comment: That comment is in itself confusing! Please edit your question to clarify rather than using the comments.